# Problem with Django url regular expression

Tags: python, regex, django

I am attempting to define a search url using Django with the following structure

```
www.example.com/afdata/search?device=television&category=news&query=channel&limit=30/
```

My goal is to extract the values `television`, `news`, `channel` and `30` from the above url and pass it to a view defined as follows

```
def search(request, device='all', category='single', query='', limit=30):
    return HttpResponse("device=%s, category=%s, query=%s, limit=%d", device, category, query, limit)
```

`afdata` is the app and in the url configuration file I defined the url as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('afdata.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^search?device=(?P<device>.*)&category=(?P<category>.*)&query=(?P<query>.*)&limit=(?P<limit>d+)/$', 'search')
)
```

When I run using the above search query in the browser, I get `500 Internal Server Error`. `index` responds fine. Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i suggest that you change your search url to:

```
(r'^search', 'search')
```

then in your view do

```
def search(request):
    device = request.GET.get('device', 'all')
    category = request.GET.get('category', 'single')
    query = request.GET.get('query', '')
    limit = request.GET.get('limit', 30)

   return HttpResponse("device=%s, category=%s, query=%s, limit=%d", device, category, query, limit)
```

This is much more robust and changeable and flexible.

Comment: @James, would the url be structured as follows? `www.example.com/search?device=television?category=news?query=channel?limit=30`

Comment: @david it would be `www.example.com/search?device=television&category=news&query=channel&limit=30` as you can't have `?` in a url except to separate the url from the parameters

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure for more information about query strings/url

Answer (score 3):

Django's URL patterns don't match the query part of the URL (the part starting with the `?`). You only do what you're trying to do if you have parameters embedded *in the URL structure itself*.

See [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against) for the exact details.

So if your URL were:

```
www.example.com/afdata/search/device/television/category/news/query/channel/limit/30/
```

*Then* you would match it with an URL pattern like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('afdata.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^search/device/(?P<device>.*)/category/(?P<category>.*)/query/(?P<query>.*)/limit/(?P<limit>d+)/$', 'search')
)
```

(This would be a somewhat odd URL convention, but it would work.)

If your URLs have queries in them, you match just the part before the `?` and then your view needs to parse out the parameters from `request.GET`. (If you already have a function like that in your example, it's easy enough to write some glue code to pass the arguments.)

Answer (score 1):

Look in your Apache logs for the stacktrace. also: you sure you don't mean HTTPResponse not HTTPRequest on the 2nd line of your search()?

Comment: Yes, `HttpResponse` is correct. I tried it but still the same problem. I will look at the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

By using `.*` Django might be grabbing up through your `&category`. Even if this is not the case, it is usually good practice to structure a regex in a way that disallows this. I would consider changing your `.*` to `[^&]*`